# What is a split $\mathbb{K}$-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

After some considerations the article I'm reading concludes: "...hence H is a simple split $\mathbb{K}$-algebra".
I can't find this definition anywhere: what does "split" mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this note](http://www.math.umn.edu/~bahra004/splitting-field.pdf), a split $k$-algebra $A$ is a $k$-algebra all of whose simple modules $M$ are absolutely simple, in the sense that after extension of scalars $M \mapsto M \otimes_k L$ (where $k \to L$ is a field extension) they remain simple.

If $A$ is semisimple, I believe this condition is equivalent to the condition that $A$ is a finite product of matrix algebras $M_n(k)$. And if $A$ is (finite-dimensional and) simple, I believe this condition is equivalent to the condition that $A$ is a matrix algebra $M_n(k)$.

The terminology is, as far as I know, motivated by a generalization of the notion of splitting field of a polynomial. A splitting field for a $k$-algebra is a field extension $k \to L$ such that $A \otimes_k L$ is split, and in the special case $A = k[x]/f(x)$ this is the same thing as a splitting field of $f(x)$.

Comment: this makes a lot of sense in the context I am in. Thank you.

Comment: The link is invalid now. May I ask for a new one? Thanks a lot, since there are few references for this.

Comment: @ZhenhuiDing  see Pierce's book "Associative Algebras".