# What is split semisimple algebra over field k

Tags: representation-theory, terminology

I can't find the definition of this terminology. Actually, there is a similar question ['what is the split k-algebra?'](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530451/what-is-a-split-mathbbk-algebra). But the notes in the answer is unavailable and I can't add comments somehow. So I ask a new question.

Comment: That other question answers it: a split semisimple $k$-algebra is a finite direct product of matrix algebras $M_n(k)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you for your answer. But it makes me a little confused: Since for finite index, the direct sum is the 'same' as direct product., then Wedderburn-Artin theorem shows that any finite semisimple algebra satisfies the definition, what is the meaning of this defination? Is for infinite dimension algebra?

Comment: That's not true. By Artin-Wedderburn a semisimple $k$-algebra is a finite direct product of matrix algebras $M_n(D)$ where $D$ is a division algebra over $k$. "Split" requires that each of these division algebras be $k$ itself.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thats right! Thank you for telling me !!! It makes us avoid the algebraic closure condition in the theorem. Is there any reference talk about this?

Comment: Section 3.6 in the book Finite Dimensional Algebras by Yurij A. Drozd Vladimir and V. Kirichenko has a discussion on this. It gives the non-semisimple version of “split algebras”, i.e. an algebra $A$ is called split if $A/J(A)$ is (semisimple) split in the sense of what @QiaochuYuan said. Since we are talking about finite dimensional algebras,  $A/J(A)$ is always semisimple (also, even if $A$ is not necessarily finite dimensional, the condition that $A/J(A)$ is a finite product of matrix algebras over $k$ will guarantee that it’s semisimple).